# Swift 4: Unrecognized selector sent to instance when calling a function inside another class

Tags: ios, swift, selector

For my application, I am working without storyboards. For that reason, I am trying to keep my ViewController clutter free by storing larger functions inside another class and calling them when needed.

For some reason, when I call my functions with #Selector I get a crash stating "Unrecognized selector sent to instance".

When I store my function inside the same ViewController as the #Selector it works just fine.

**The Following Code Below Works**

**View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)


}

lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = Color.darkBlue
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LoginFunctions.handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

    @objc func handleLogin() {
    print("Logging In!!!")
    }

}
```

*What I am trying to achieve*

**The code below does not work**

**View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)


}

lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = Color.darkBlue
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LoginFunctions.handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

}
```

**LoginFunctions**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LoginFunctions {

@objc func handleLogin() {
    print("Logging In!!!")
}
}
```

I have been trying to debug this for days with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the complete and exact error message in your question and point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: You should create another method in ViewController. Add target for your button to that method. Then call your handleLogin in that new method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reference to your LoginFunctions from your `ViewController`. And you pass `self` as the target to the button but `self` doesn't have a `handleLogin` method.

You need to hold and instance of `LoginFunctions` in your `ViewController` class. Then pass that reference as the target instead of `self`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let functions = LoginFunctions()

    lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = Color.darkBlue
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

        button.addTarget(functions, action: #selector(LoginFunctions.handleLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. I always thought the "self" in the #selector function referred to the button that was triggering the action. I guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: Nope. `button` is the button. The selector is called on the specified target. If you want the selector to know which button triggered the selector being called, you need to add the button as a parameter to the selector.

Comment: In my case it was occurring because I forgot to change Module in Custom Class (Main.storyboard) because I reused a project for a new one

Answer (score 2):

To add a target to a class it must contain the func in selector , you may try this to share method between viewControllers

```
extension UIViewController 
{
    @objc func handleLogin() {
         print("Logging In!!!")
    }

}
```